# package javax.jws does not exist

Tags: java

I am trying to implement *soap web service* by using Java. It is showing package *javax.jws* does not exist. I have added the path to jdk also. I am new to Java, please help me.

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style=SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class Hello {
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read [the java 9 migration guide](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-migration-guide/#Dependencies-On-Java-EE-Modules). Or see [Replacements for deprecated JPMS modules with Java EE APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis).

Short version: use the reference implementation of JAX-WS.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```