# package javax.jws does not exist. JDK 1.7

Tags: apt, package-management, java, eclipse, jdk

I am trying to run an old maven project, a Website Application from my company, so I can do some changes for an update.
Currently, I'm still making some changes in pom.xml file because some library is not available in the repository. And after some configuration, I've been stuck in this error while I try to run the project using **Tomcat Server 7** with **JDK 1.7**. It is showing that:

> error: package javax.jws does not exist
> import javax.jws.WebMethod;

> error: package javax.jws does not exist
> import javax.jws.WebService;

so I search and found this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1149525/1644122

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I have add this library and it went well when I build it using maven.
But, this error appears when I do "run on server" in eclipse.

> Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class [com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContainerInitializer])

I believe that the dependency that I add before require JDK 1.8 or above to run. The problem is, I need to  to make it run in our tomcat server for a development environtment.

Now, the question is, Is there library that includes package javax.jws and support **JDK 1.7**?

Or Is there any way to handle this issue?

I'm newbie in Java. This project really driving me crazy :(

Please help me.

Comment: You've provided no OS/product/release details; so currently we're limited in any help we can offer. What are you running?

Comment: I edit my question a little bit. I'm not really sure what "OS/product/release" means. Could you please explain a little bit what I need to provide? I'm running a Web application.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes, this is not a programming Q&A site.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.